# Pandas INT column datatype changes depending on how the data is called (BUG?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe `XY` with two columns, one is an integer column, the other one a float column.

The integer column is called `Count` (with a capital C to avoid problems) and its unique values are these:

```
XY["Count"].unique()
array([ 38,   7,   1,  13,   3,  28,   5,   6,   4,  11,   9,   2,   8,
        22,  12,  15,  20,  17,  18,  10,  40,  14,  16,  24,  25,  39,
        81,  19,  21, 110,  88,  23,  29,  46,  26,  32,  36,  43,  96,
        34,  47,  61,  35,  56,  41,  33,  30,  53,  27,  54,  37,  65,
        31,  52,  42,  93,  76,  57,  49,  71,  48,  77,  50,  84,  44,
        69,  75,  58,  60,  55,  72, 536,  67,  80,  64,  82, 101,  99,
       104,  68,  45,  66,  87,  90,  78,  74,  62,  73,  63,  86, 108,
       105, 197, 118, 209,  70,  59,  98,  97,  94,  79,  89,  51,  83,
        85, 221, 322, 164, 116, 103, 107, 102, 143,  91,  95,  92, 120,
       188, 148, 106, 179, 124, 165, 122, 113, 119, 169, 109, 138, 123,
       121, 125, 129, 177, 137, 206, 127, 115, 111, 131, 117, 128, 100,
       126, 163, 133, 186, 114, 203, 135, 141, 227, 162], dtype=int64)
```

As you can see it's only integers and `numpy` interprets it correctly as `int64`.

Now lets look at extracting a single value:

```
XY["Count"][0]
38
XY["Count"][0].dtype
numpy.int32

XY.ix[0,"Count"]
38
XY.ix[0,"Count"].dtype
numpy.int32
```

So direct indexing and `ix` with column label give back `int32`.

```
XY.loc[0,"Count"]
38.0
XY.loc[0,"Count"].dtype
numpy.float64

XY.ix[0,0]
38.0
XY.ix[0,0].dtype
numpy.float64

XY.iloc[0,0]
38.0
XY.iloc[0,0].dtype
numpy.float64
```

But `loc`, `iloc`, and index-based `ix` report the format as `float64`.

Now when I'm directly extracting the values from the internal `numpy` array, it's also a `float64`. Remember that my second column is a float column.

```
XY.values[0,0]
38.0
XY.values[0,0].dtype
numpy.float64
```

I don't know if I'm missing something, but this is really inconsistent and causes problems since I need to specifically return the data in integer format. I presume it's a bug.

EDIT 1:

When testing with a dataframe that has ONLY the integer column every method returned `int32`, so it seems the problem comes from the second column and inconsistent internal data conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get back a float because each row of your dataframe contains a mix of integer and float types. Upon selecting a row index with `ix` or `loc`, integers are being converted to floats. To get around this, you could use loc to select from just the required column and not the whole dataframe:

```
XY['Count'].loc[4]
```

Comment: But `XY.ix[0,"Count"]` does return an integer while `XY.ix[0,0]` returns a float, and both are selecting a row index. The suggestion works with all of them though, thanks.

Comment: If you try this: `XY['Count'].ix[0:]` ?
And I think this documentation might help you: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#integer-indexing

Comment: That code (without the `:`) does also return `int64`. But that leaves the problem that `int64` is sometimes returned as `float64` and sometimes not. And the only case when the datatype should be changed like that is when `NaN` values are involved. So while I workarounds exist it shouldn't happen in the first place and I was wondering if it's a bug or if it's documented as a caveat. I couldn't find anything in the link you provided.

Comment: I think you should report it to the developers as possible bug.

Comment: Already did. It was marked a duplicate of an existing problem, so they know about it.